# Stata: Turning One Variable into Multiple, with each as Value or 0

Tags: stata

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
clear 
input  SubjectID  DecisionID  AltID  my_alpha 
 1   1   1   0.4  
 1   1   2   0.4  
 1   2   1   0.6  
 1   2   2   0.6  
 2   1   1   0.8  
 2   1   2   0.8  
 2   2   1   0.5  
 2   2   2   0.5  
 end
```

I want to create a new variable for each value of `AltID` that depends on the value of `my_alpha`. In this scenario, there would now be `AltID_alpha_1` and `AltID_alpha_2`. `AltID_alpha_1` would be equal to `my_alpha` when `AltID` is `1`, and equal to `0` otherwise. Similarly, `AltID_alpha_2` would be equal to `my_alpha` when `AltID` is equal to `2`, and equal to `0` otherwise. That is, it should look like this:

| **SubjectID**  | **DecisionID** | **AltID** | **my_alpha** | **alpha_AltID_1** | **alpha_AltID_2** |
| 1 ------------ | 1 ------------ | 1 -----   | 0.4 -------- | 0.4--------------- | 0----------------- |
| 1 ------------ | 1 ------------ | 2 -----   | 0.4 -------- | 0----------------- | 0.4--------------- |
| 1 ------------ | 2 ------------ | 1 -----   | 0.6 -------- | 0.6--------------- | 0----------------- |
| 1 ------------ | 2 ------------ | 2 -----   | 0.6 -------- | 0----------------- | 0.6--------------- |
| 2 ------------ | 1 ------------ | 1 -----   | 0.8 -------- | 0.8--------------- | 0----------------- |
| 2 ------------ | 1 ------------ | 2 -----   | 0.8 -------- | 0----------------- | 0.8--------------- |
| 2 ------------ | 2 ------------ | 1 -----   | 0.5 -------- | 0.5--------------- | 0----------------- |
| 2 ------------ | 2 ------------ | 2 -----   | 0.5 -------- | 0----------------- | 0.5--------------- |

The problem is that in my actual data, I have well over a million observations, 5151 values for `AltID`, and need to create variables for both `my_alpha` and `my_beta` (at a minimum). I need a way to do this "quickly".

I tried using a `foreach` loop to create the variables, but I had to cut it off after it had been running for 20 hours (on my desktop that has 24 GB of RAM). I was able to use the command `quietly tab AltID, gen(alpha_AltID_)` to get `0`'s in the proper places and `1`'s elsewhere, which took only a few seconds, but I then need a loop that replaces all the `1`'s with proper values, which seems to be taking roughly two hours (at the current pace). Does anyone have a more time-efficient solution?

Comment: I edited your first listing, which makes sense, but contains irrelevant characters, to something more convenient for import.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do this with your example.

```
clear 
input  SubjectID  DecisionID  AltID  my_alpha 
 1   1   1   0.4  
 1   1   2   0.4  
 1   2   1   0.6  
 1   2   2   0.6  
 2   1   1   0.8  
 2   1   2   0.8  
 2   2   1   0.5  
 2   2   2   0.5  
 end 

 gen alpha_AltID_1 = cond(AltID == 1, my_alpha, 0) 
 gen alpha_AltID_2 = cond(AltID == 2, my_alpha, 0) 

 separate my_alpha, by(AltID) 
 mvencode my_alpha?, mv(0) 

 list AltID *alpha*, sep(0)

     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
     | AltID   my_alpha   alpha_~1   alpha_~2   my_alp~1   my_alp~2 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1         .4         .4          0         .4          0 |
  2. |     2         .4          0         .4          0         .4 |
  3. |     1         .6         .6          0         .6          0 |
  4. |     2         .6          0         .6          0         .6 |
  5. |     1         .8         .8          0         .8          0 |
  6. |     2         .8          0         .8          0         .8 |
  7. |     1         .5         .5          0         .5          0 |
  8. |     2         .5          0         .5          0         .5 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, what about your real case? The `separate`/`mvencode` method should work. So should this if your ids go from 1 to 5151:

```
forval j = 1/5151 { 
    gen alpha_AltID_`j' = cond(AltID == `j', my_alpha, 0) 
}
```

If your ids are not so well behaved, then tell us how so.

It's difficult to believe that any loop code would take as long as you report, but since you don't show us the code, detailed comment is difficult.

All that said, why you do need one variable to be mapped to thousands?